# How to call OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog in cdev

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

I have created some tools using visual studio (C#) and create the engine in cdev (C code) by calling cdev.exe. In visual studio, user needs to choose file by clicking the button OpenFileDialog and save it in FolderBrowserDialog. Then, need to click a button that calls the cdev (.exe) as engine to run the process. All the process are code using c code. 
The question is how can I call the OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog from Visual Studio in Cdev? And need to save it as .jpeg in FolderBrowserDialog

This is Visual studio (C#) code for OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
        choofdlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
        choofdlog.Multiselect = true;

        if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = choofdlog.FileName;
        else
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            textBox2.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        else
            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

while this is my code in Cdev

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){    
char cname[1000]="C:\\PendriveCarve.001",auditTrail[50]; //choose file
{
    //process

}
sprintf(auditTrail, "C:\\%d.jpeg", i); //save as jpeg
}
```

i'm sorry for my bad english and explaination

Comment: If you mean the dialogs that are part of `System.Windows.Forms`, the answer probably is "you can't". Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve (see also [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). My first doubt would be whether you need C code *at all*. If you do, there might be options communicating through a pipe or whatever else, depending on what exactly you try to do.

Comment: so how i want to call the function? am i need to call lib?

Comment: You can't simply "call" a *managed code* function from native code.